# Converting a while loop to a for loop

Tags: delphi

How should I convert this while loop into a for loop?

```
const
  TheRightWord = 'hello';
  MaximumTries = 3;
var
  NTries : integer;
  AWord : string;
begin
  NTries := 1;
  AWord := ' ';
  while (AWord <> TheRightWord) and (NTries <= MaximumTries) do
```

---

I thought this would be the answer:

```
for (AWord <> TheRightWord) and (NTries <= MaximumTries) do
```

Must I just put a `for` inplace of the `while`? Or is it `for i := 1 to 3 do`?

Comment: no i want to make a program that askes for a password  ....

Comment: and if 3 tries fail then it lockes you out but i want to use a for loop instead of a while

Comment: "For" loop does not accepts boolean statements. It's gonna be just "for i := 1 to 3 do" with the rest of logic inside

Comment: I can't understand why you need this ; except you are forced to do this ,there is no need to convert a while loop into a for loop because while loop is considered to be perform well than for loop

Answer (score 7):

```
  for numtries := 1 to maxnumtries do begin
    if AWord = TheRightWord then
      break;
      ...
```

How to determine success or failure when exiting the loop (or, for that matter, how to iterate through different values of "AWord") is an exercise for the student :-)

Comment: Strictly, this is the correct answer to the question, but personally I dislike using 'break'.  For that reason I would have used a while loop in the first place.